# c++: How to obtain sub-string of file path, without file name

Tags: c++, stdstring

I have a a file path as 
    `std::string`

For example: 
    `C:\\folder1\\folder2\\file.dll`

I want to get the folder path

For example:
   C:\folder1\folder2\.

I tried
    `str=path.substr(0,path.find_last_of("\\/"))`

But, this ommits the last `\\` also.

Comment: so add 1 to the result of find_last_of

Comment: Instead of handling paths and their handling yourself, I recommend you use either [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) (if your compiler is new enough to have C++17, or otherwise [Boost filesystem `path`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path) otherwise). It will make all your path handling *so* much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to boost, use:

```
boost::filesystem::path(str).root_path();
```

and with C++17:

```
std::filesystem::path(str).root_path();
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use [`std::filesystem::parent_path()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/parent_path):

  ```
  std::filesystem::path p{ "c:\\temp\\test.txt" };
  std::cout << "Parent: " << p.parent_path() << std::endl; // will output c:\temp
  ```
- If you are using VS 2017, `filesystem` is available under `experimental` namespace:

  ```
  std::experimental::filesystem::path p{ "c:\\temp\\test.txt" };
  ```
- Under Windows you may also combine [`_splitpath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/splitpath-wsplitpath?view=vs-2017) and [_makepath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/makepath-wmakepath?view=vs-2017) to build the parent path.